# Django admin add popup not working with many-to-many attribute on itself

Tags: django, many-to-many, admin, m2m

Im trying to use in django admin a simple model like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    valuem2m = models.ManyToManyField("Model1", related_name="model1", blank=True)
```

When try to add values in admin, if I try to open more than 1 popup, it didn't open another window, only redirect to the next form.
[first emergent window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8ojj.png)
When I save this gives me this error.

```
pup_response.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: opener.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup is not a function
    at popup_response.js:13:16
```

[window broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNDk.png)

This is because the autogenerated id of the add button is the same of the child add button.
(add_id_valuem2m).
[DevTools id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rrGk.png)

There is a way to make this work?